# Restricted domain of $\sin (2x)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The "restricted" domain of $\sin x$ is $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

So what should be the domain of $\sin (2x)$; My say is that $2x$ belongs to $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ as I understand that the argument inside the function or the "input" values should remain the same irrespective of the input values being $2x$ or $3x$. All the input values should have the same domain as that of $\sin x$

$2x$ belongs to $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

$x$ belongs to $[-\pi/4,\pi/4]$

What I did in the last step is divide the domain by $2$ so that I get corresponding values of $x$ which satisfy the domain.

I can feel that somethings fundamentally wrong with my reasoning. Please correct me.

Edit 1- I know that I might be a bit annoying right now, but just to be super sure, I need to again know weather the argument in the pink box is right.
[image]

In the above question we are supposed to find the intervals in which the function $f(x) = \sin 2x$ in which the function is strictly increasing.

M1 stands for method 1 which you might as well ignore. I am concerned about method 2.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser thanks for the tip

Comment: The restriction of the domain is made to make $\sin(x)$ strictly monoton increasing making it invertible. One possibility is to use the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Your argument how you can modify this for $\sin(2x)$ or similar expressions , is valid.

Comment: ohhh, my math teacher says I am wrong and instead says that the domain should be   [-pi,pi]. He just multiplies the domain of sin(x) with 2 instead of dividing it by 2 as I did and above all that he stares at my face and says again and again that I should multiply it by 2 and my logic doesn't make any sense

Comment: *says that the domain should be [-pi,pi]* No it's wrong. Your work is correct. Restricted domain is $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

Comment: How can I make my math teacher understand that I am right? He needs an academic arguement, like a series of statements which I am not able to put forth properly.

Comment: "The function is not one-one in $[-\pi, \pi]$ and hence is not invertible." I think this reasoning would be enough.

Comment: "Dividing the domain by $2$" is a little unclear, but you can argue that
$$
-\frac{\pi}{2}\le 2x \le \frac{\pi}{2} \implies -\frac{\pi}{4}\le x \le \frac{\pi}{4} \, .
$$

Comment: @Ipsy-Doopsy Just demonstrate the teacher that there are two distinct values $x,y$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ with $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$ , for example $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ , $y=\frac{3\pi}{4}$. This shows that $[-\pi,\pi]$ does not work.